# CSS unicode-range for CJK characters

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, cjk, octicons

My preferred font is Inconsolata, which messes up GitHub's octicon web font.  Yesterday I updated my user stylesheet for Google Chrome to properly display the octicon font on GitHub, so today I'm trying to get the CJK characters to display correctly.

My CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'cjk';
  src: local('monospace');
  unicode-range: U+3000-30FF, U+FF00-FFEF, U+4E00-9FAF;
}

* { font-family: cjk, inconsolata !important; }
*[class*="octicon"]  { font-family: octicons !important; }
```

I capture the complete CJK range, but the characters still don't show correctly.  Am I using the wrong local font?  (I'm running Debian 6.)

UPDATE: the fix was simply installing the `ttf-takao` package.

The working code, with instructions:

https://github.com/cureadvocate/chrome-user-stylesheet

Comment: What does that “messes up” mean? Do you actually have `inconslata` in the CSS code? What are you trying to accomplish, and exactly how does it fail? Why are you using the generic name `monospace`, if this is about a user style sheet?

Comment: Messes up meaning the icons don't show, but the `*[class*=]` rule fixes that.  The Inconsolata font lacks a lot of the unicode characters, so visiting a Japanese site (e.g.,gizmodo.jp) shows a lot of empty boxes instead of the kana and kanji.  A non-customized Chrome displays the kana and kanji fine with `font-family: monospace`, so I tried that in `src`.

Comment: @StevenEdwards What Jukka tried to say was you have Inconsolata misspelled in your CSS. Also, you misspelled Octicons in your prose.

Comment: @MrLister thank you for pointing out the typos. :)  That said, the css still doesn't show CJK characters like Hiragana and Katakana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Debian issue.  I needed to install the `ttf-takao` package, which corrected everything.

I feel dumb. :)

Comment: Don't feel _too_ dumb. I also have Debian and I didn't know the answer, because I never heard of ttf-takao.

Comment: Thanks.  Credit goes to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Installing_Japanese_character_sets